# Calculus: Find an upper bound for an estimate of the area

Tags: calculus

Using n=6 rectangles, find an upper bound for an estimate of the area under the parabola y=x^2 from x=0 to x=1. Hint: use the right side of each rectangle as its height.

This is a calculus problem part of integral. I dont understand how to solve it.

Comment: Draw a picture!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have to use equal width of rectangles. Then the width of the rectangles are $\frac{1-0}6$.

And the heights of the rectangles are $\left(0+\frac16\right)^2, \left(0+2\times\frac16\right)^2, \left(0+3\times\frac16\right)^2, \ldots$ respectively.

Answer (score 4):

An upper bound estimate would be:

$$E \le h | f(b) - f(a) | = \dfrac{1}{6} |f(1) - f(0)| = \dfrac{1}{6}$$

If we draw the picture using six-rectangles and superimpose the parabola, we get:

[image]

Using the Right-Hand Riemann sum, we have:

$$I = h \sum_{n=1}^6 f(n/6) = \dfrac{1}{6} \left(f(1/6) + f(2/6) + f(3/6) + f(4/6) + f(5/6) + f(6/6) \right) = 0.421296$$

See if you can derive the two items above.

The actual integral result is:

$$\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^2 dx  = \dfrac{1}{3}$$

Now compare the Riemann result to actual and see if that matches what the error estimate $E$ provided.